# Is my netbook good enough to use Kubuntu?

Tags: samsung, system-requirements

I have a rather slow Samsung netbook and I would like to know someone's opinion as to whether it is good enough for Kubuntu, or I should use Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead.

Here are the numbers:
processor: AMD quad-core up to 1.4 GHz
Ram: 3.3 Gb

So what do you think: should I use Kubuntu or the lighter versions?

Comment: You didn't state your HDD size but generally ubuntu doesn't consume a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Kubuntu running alone only uses around 500 - 600MB of RAM and 1.4 GHz is not god-awful slow. It would work perfectly as a web browser/word processor/Youtube/Music sort of machine.
 Do consider one of the lighter flavors if you need to squeeze all the power you can get out of it though.